# gRPC bi-directional stream processing with multi-threaded clients

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

A gRPC newbie question here.

We have a source system that exposes a bi directional gRPC stream. In order to scale our application, we wanted to process the stream data in parallel. Is it possible to have concurrent / multiple gRPC clients consuming from the stream without any conflicts in data processing / during acknowledgement process etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this in the context of a single streaming call? In that case the answer is no. You have a single gRPC client receiving one response stream and it can use worker threads to hand off messages from the stream.

If you are thinking of multiple gRPC clients in an application talking to the same server (I don't see any advantage of doing that) each one will make a separate call and will receive a separate response stream.